# How change Lucida font size to 8.5pt on 11.7pt?

Tags: fontsize, lucida

In *The LaTeX Companion, Third Edition*, page 23, the author states that the book is set in Lucida fonts with a measure of 8.5pt/11.7pt (that is, 8.5pt on 11.7pt)

How does one globally set those font and leading sizes globally for a document when using the `lucidabr` package?

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Of course I searched first! Lots of hits about changing to `\large`, etc. And I thought what I wanted was `\fontsize`, but I was not able to find an explicit description of how to use it. David Carlisle's answer did tell me what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\fontsize{8.5}{11.7}\selectfont` will select that font size.

You may want to redefine `\normalsize` to use that, and may also want to redefine `\small` and friends to be suitable relative sizes.

eg `size10.clo` used for 10pt `article` has the following
so you may want a similar  block with values around 85% of these...

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt  % 10pt/12pt
                           %%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\ifx\MakeRobust\@undefined \else
    \MakeRobust\normalsize
\fi
\DeclareRobustCommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{11}%   9pt/11pt
                       %%%%%%%%%%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\DeclareRobustCommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt}
\DeclareRobustCommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}
```

Comment: I just found the `fontsize` package, which seems to take care of resetting the meaning of `\small`, etc., according to the setting for `\normalsize` via its `\changefontsize` command (where the order of the two arguments is the *reverse* of the arguments to `\fontsize`!